# What ZFS pool, vdev and dataset properties should most people use?

Tags: zfs, zfsonlinux, openzfs

ZFS has many different configurable properties [for pools](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/man/master/7/zpoolprops.7.html), [for vdevs](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/man/master/7/vdevprops.7.html) and [for datasets](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/man/master/7/zfsprops.7.html). Many of those can be changed at any point, but some can only be set at creation time (or only affect data written afterwards so *should* really be set at creation time).

As a noob I searched for many different questions and found several properties that were suggested to be set a lot.

Obviously each use case will have little differences on what properties make sense, but there seems to be a common set of properties that most zfs users should use. I'm thinking of those properties for which one should have an active reason *not* to use them. What are those and why?

Comment: ZFS has lots of islands of knowledge. Many of the tuning settings I've recommended over the years were intended for server-based solutions and storage  appliances. As ZFS has been adopted by the mainstream (for better or worse), many of these recommendations no longer apply. I respect that people want to use ZFS on workstations, as a boot/root, on Windows and Mac... but those use cases come into conflict when it comes to defining best practices.

Comment: Fair, I was pondering if serverfault or unix.SE was the better site for these kinds of question, which basically would map to the target audience. I was hoping that there is at least some shared kernel of "truth" that would apply to 90%+ of the use cases.

Answer (score 2):

(Disclaimer: as a ZFS beginner, this is only my understanding this far and is meant as a impetus for more complete and reliable information from others).

### Pool properties

- `ashift=12`

  At a basic level this [ensures that read/write operations of ZFS align with the block boundaries of the underlying storage](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/man/master/7/zpoolprops.7.html#ashift). *Theoretically* for 512-byte blocks `ashift=9` would be fine, but drives with those are rare these days and the penalty for having `ashift` set "too high" is rather low.
- `autotrim=on`

  Automatically [inform the underlying block storage when some space is no longer needed](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/man/master/7/zpoolprops.7.html#autotrim). Especially useful on SSDs but seems to not hurt on classic HDDs either (though it likely won't help there).

### Dataset properties

These can be specified with `zfs create -o` or via the `-O` switch of `zpool create` for the root filesystem (which will by default be inherited to others).

- `xattr=sa`

  The significantly increases the performance of xattr with no real drawback. ([Only available on Linux](https://openzfs.org/wiki/Platform_code_differences) for now).
- `dnodesize=auto`

  This property should be used when using `xattr=sa`. The primary reason not to use these is [interacting with systems that don't support the required ZFS feature](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/man/master/7/zfsprops.7.html#dnodesize).
- `relatime=on`

  Tracking the access time of files can be very expensive even in read-only interaction. `relatime` signficiantly reduces the granularity/frequency of these updates at the cost of less precise information in the `atime` property (while maintaining some commonly require invariants). Note that this is the default for almost all filesystems on Linux for a long while for now. If one needs precise `atime` information, then don't turn this on. If one knows that `atime` is never needed then `atime=off` provides even better performance.
- `normalization=formD`

  This will ensure that file names are always normalized the same way. As a major side-effect this also means that the file system will treat file names as UTF-8 encoded and can no longer store file names with certain "broken" names that other file systems accept. If this isn't desired, then leave this out.
- `compression=lz4`

  The consensus seems to be that the cost of compression is so low on modern hardware that this has effectively only upside. Datasets that store predominantly already-heavily-compressed data might want to turn this off.
- no `recordsize`

  The default recordsize seems to be a good middle ground for many usecases, but some use cases like databases might benefit from specific values.

#### Sources

- [Debian Root on ZFS](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Getting%20Started/Debian/Debian%20Bullseye%20Root%20on%20ZFS.html#step-2-disk-formatting)
- Many individual forum posts